# Ubuntu 13.10, format the entire harddrive and install Windows 8.1

Tags: grub2, 13.10, windows, format, 8.10

I'm stuck with my laptop as I explained here :[Windows 8.1 doesn't appear in GRUB2](https://askubuntu.com/q/412786/241530)
I can't find a solution.
To resume: I have a Asus N53S with ubuntu 13.10 installed and Windows 8.1 but GRUB can't see it. (See the refered post for details)

My question is :
If I format the entire disk, Ubuntu and windows, and create my partitions with the Windows 8.1 disk (just before installation), my hard drive will be totaly empty and I will install only Windows. Will I boot automaticaly on Windows? I mean, will GRUB be erased after the formatting? And the windows boot manager will appear?

Is you don't understand what I mean, please, ask questions.

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grub will be erased after formatting.

Windows boot manager will be reinstalled after Windows installation.

Windows will automatically boot into windows and will not see any other OSs.

Comment: That's perfect and I'm now confident :-)
Thanks you